# Toggle Div with same ID name into a loop

Tags: javascript, java, html

I got values into these two arrays parsed HTML with nokogiri. I'm struggling with toggle into my views I can able to show only first div content. When I would like to show second div contents named `selectPeriodRangePanel` by pressing named `period_select_range_btn` link I show always first div contents.

```
@name= ['HTML','Links','Images','Code','Lists']
@content= ['Examples in Every Chapter',
      'Links is an open source text',
      'Browse through dozens of free flower images',
      'Code.org thanks its supporters',
      'If you loved Winston']

<% for i in 1..5 %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <%= @name[i] %>
                <a id="period_select_range_btn">Show Tag</a>
            </div>
            <div id="selectPeriodRangePanel" style="display:none">
                <div class="col">           
                    <div><%= @content[i]%></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("click", function(e) {
       var el = $(e.target).closest("#selectPeriodRangePanel, #period_select_range_btn").length != 0;
       $("#selectPeriodRangePanel"+ id).toggle(el);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Few questions.  Is this file a JSP?  Are you using jQuery?

Comment: You're using the same ID on multiple elements, IDs are meant to be unique, class names are more appropriate for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, having more than one element with the same ID is invalid and while browsers won't stop you from doing it, both JavaScript and jQuery will only recognize the first element that has the ID . . . all others with it will be ignored.

As mentioned in the comments, if you need to group elements together, a common class is a better way to handle it . . . keep the IDs unique.